# Signal Analysis in Octave

Tags: signals, octave, analysis

Dears,

I would like to ask you for help. Since I do not have a signal pkg in Matlab I tried to run the script with Octave. Unfortunately, I am struggling with optimization. Code crashed with the `[Horizontal_Peaks_ROI_3, Loc1_ROI_3] = findpeaks(double(line_image_ROI_3(i).ESF), 'MinPeakDistance',8);` Do you have any idea, where I did mistake, please?

Here you are my minimal reproducible example:

```
line_image_ROI_3 = struct('ESF', zeros(0),'LSF',zeros(0), 'Peaks',zeros(1,2), 'Valleys',zeros(1,2));
mass_center_ROI_3 = zeros(1,size(cropped_image_Horizontal_ROI_3,1));
pixel_position_ROI_3 = 1:size(cropped_image_Horizontal_ROI_3,1);
i=1;j=1;
Max_Peaks=zeros(1,12);
for i = 1 :StepWidth:size(cropped_image_Horizontal_ROI_3,1)
    %get the column_ROI_3 of the image
    line_image_ROI_3(i).ESF = cropped_image_Horizontal_ROI_3(:,i)';
    SignalROI3(j,:)=cropped_image_Horizontal_ROI_3(:,i)' 
    subplot(4,5,j+3)
    plot(line_image_ROI_3(i).ESF);
    axis tight;
    hold on;
    [Horizontal_Peaks_ROI_3, Loc1_ROI_3] = findpeaks(double(line_image_ROI_3(i).ESF), 'MinPeakDistance',8);
    line_image_ROI_3(j).Peaks=[Loc1_ROI_3', Horizontal_Peaks_ROI_3'];

    plot(Loc1_ROI_3,Horizontal_Peaks_ROI_3,'or');
    Max_Avg_V_ROI_3(j)=mean(Horizontal_Peaks_ROI_3);
    x1_ROI_3=[0 length(line_image_ROI_3(i).ESF)];
    y1_ROI_3=[Max_Avg_V_ROI_3(j) Max_Avg_V_ROI_3(j)];
    plot(x1_ROI_3,y1_ROI_3,'--g'); % Average Max
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: please better describe what you mean by 'crash'.  was there an error message? did the script stop, did the whole program close, did the operating system lock up, was there physical damage?  ;)

Comment: it will help an example of data to test the code. And the value of StepWidth

Comment: Hello, it crashed because of: error: Data contains negative values. You may want to "DoubleSided" option
error: called from
    findpeaks at line 181 column 5
    MTF_Horizontal_v10_25052020 at line 177 column 44

Comment: What the algorithm should do: Upload and crop image. The the cropped image should be evaluated according to the script what I shared with you. Variables: StepWidth=10; CF=0.75; are fixed value. Thank you in advance